What’s the difference between “individuals” and “people”?
I once read a question in which @FumberFingers said that “individuals” are often used when it comes to crime. But today, I saw a case in which “individuals” is used in a different sense:

Wealthy individuals currently account for about 75 per cent of hedge fund investment, and institutions make up the other 25 per cent.

So in which cases can I use “people” and “individuals” interchangeably?

I don’t think that “individuals” are often used when it comes to crime. Can you show that which question that @FumberFingers said that?

Cite your source please.

There are a few nuanced differences. "Individuals" is perhaps more formal than "people". But the main difference is that the word "individuals" better emphasises the individuality of those to whom it refers. That might seem obvious - but "people" is such a generic term and can sound like you are assuming all "wealthy people" are the same and can be grouped together. Some object strongly to generalisations - for example, terms like "women" or "black people", when used to make generalisations, can be perceived as insulting. "Wealthy people" may not be quite as generic as "the wealthy" but it could sound disparaging in certain contexts.
